# How to make flex items align right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is an excerpt of my cloning of Jobbatical.com as part of a learning project. Ignore the missing logo.

I'm trying to make the 2nd unordered list (whose list items are Log in, Join, For Companies) in the fixed navbar align right. I have tried various ways using the inspector tool, and setting margin-left: auto but for some reason I can't get it to work.

https://codepen.io/jenlky/pen/RxyyEL?editors=1100

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fix-navbar d-none d-md-flex">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="Jobbatical.com" alt="jobbatical.com" id="logo"><img src="jobbatical_logo_blue.svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" alt="Find jobs">Find jobs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" alt="Login in">Log in</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" alt="Sign up!">Join</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="for-companies">
          <a href="#" alt="Looking to hire?" id="companies-link">for companies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

/* doesnt work... */
.navbar-right {
    margin-left: auto !important;
}

li a:not(#companies-link) {
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1c75bc;
    padding: 33px 0 31px;
    margin: 0 18px;
    font-family: Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

nav .navbar-nav > li.btn > a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 4px 10px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `flex: 1` on the parent of those `ul` flex items.

The parent (`.fix-navbar`) also happens to be a flex item. It's a child of `.container-fluid`, which has `display: flex`. But flex items don't automatically get full width.

So the parent of the `ul` flex items is shrink-wrapping the content, and when you apply `margin-left: auto`, there's no extra space for it to work.

Therefore, set `flex: 1` on `.fix-navbar`. This gives it the full width of the parent, creating extra space, and enabling `margin-left: auto` to work on the children.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJxVdb?editors=1100)

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you very much. Additional thanks for the detailed explanation.